# navigating to anchors in div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML file with many `<div>` elements and I cannot navigate to anchor tags using JavaScript. I have put a demo in jsfiddle. Please see the link for JavaScript + CSS + HTML for details.

I can navigate to the "section5" but not to other sections.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/funcubes/XueyX/7)

Can anyone help me with this?

Any help would be really appreciated....

Kind regards

***Update :*** *Thanks for the response. I have updated the link with cleaned up HTML. The javascript navigation still doesn't work* :(

***Update 2:*** Thanks for the suggestions, but still not working 
**I updated it with your suggestions.. but it doesn't work. If I take out the css entry  "div.columnbreak { -webkit-column-break-after: always; the navigation works. When I put that back the navigation doesn't work***

Comment: Seems to be working in your example, no?

Comment: You also have multiple instances of <a>-elements with the same name. I see at least 3 <a>'s with "section3" value in name attribute.

Comment: @Niklas: No, if you change the javascript to point to "#section3" it will not... if you point to "#section5" it works.

Comment: @Orolin: I dont have <a> tags with same names in the HTML.

Comment: Both Jill-Jênn Vie and @CodeWeed see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XueyX/18/)

You don't need to use `<a>` element at all, you can assign unique id to your section block.

Answer (score 2):

You are not closed the tags correctly

For eg:,

**Wrong**

```
<p>This EPUB eBook is released under a Creative Commons (BY-NC-ND/3.0) Licence.
        <p>Source text and images taken from the Public Domain.</p>
```

**Correct**

```
<p>This EPUB eBook is released under a Creative Commons (BY-NC-ND/3.0) Licence.
        Source text and images taken from the Public Domain.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that... I have updated the HTML but the navigation still doesn't work !!!

Comment: Also check your anchor tag, correct format is <a name="section1"></a>

Comment: I updated it with your suggestions.. but it doesn't work. If I take out the css entry  "div.columnbreak { -webkit-column-break-after: always; }" the navigation works... if I put it back it doesn't.

Comment: @SumeshTG `name` for anchors is already deprecated. You need to use `id` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I might be reading this wrong but it looks like your tags might not be closed properly
in section  you have 2 open p's and only 1 close.

its throwing off wihch sections are in which and thats why your anchors are getting mixed up.

JSFiddle also doesn't seem to like the 3 div tags above section 3 but I havent figured out why, yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the location of the `<a>` tag. You should put it right after the `<p>` tag you're interested in.

And well, you should [tidy up your markup](http://validator.w3.org) a bit. Everyone knows Irene Adler is attracted by valid webpages.

Answer (score 0):

This is a screenshot of the markup in your jsFiddle example:

[image]

As you can see, there are multiple `<a>`'s with name value "section1", "section2" etc. This will prevent your #sectionX hash to find a unique anchor.

Comment: I honestly double checked it.. and it doesn't reflect the way showed.. I am very very sure.. I checked many times...

Comment: Well, I didn't make that screenshot in Photoshop. So Chrome atleast thinks your markup is like that.

Comment: that is strange.. hmm.. I am using Safari 6.0 in MAC OS X 4.7